# bootstrap 3 datepicker with custom theme - nasty looking

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, datepicker

I bought one of the custom Metro themes that was part of the John Papa AngularJS/Breeze courses on Pluralsight.  Everything goes well until I tried to add a Bootstrap 3 date picker to the mix.  Right out of the box, it looks nasty.

[image]

Note that the font-awesome icon is a couple of pixels smaller than the input box and that the popup has varying column widths and these weird borders and no background etc., etc.

```
     <div class="col-xs-6">
         <div class="input-group">
             <input type="text" class="form-control"
                    datepicker-popup="{{vm.dateFormat}}"
                    ng-model="vm.startDate"
                    is-open="vm.openedStart"
                    max-date="{{vm.endDate | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd'}}"
                    datepicker-options="{{vm.dateOptions}}"
                    ng-required="true"
                    show-button-bar="false"
                    show-weeks="false" />
             <span class="input-group-btn">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="vm.openStart($event)"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button>
             </span>
         </div>
    </div>
```

I seem to have this problem whenever I try and use a custom bootstrap style that I've downloaded, so I'm obviously missing something fundamental in how custom style sets work.

So given that I have a custom style, how do I go about resetting the style of the datepicker so it looks much more 'default'?  Obviously, I have to hunt down the CSS for it, and I have a customtheme.css file, but there's not much in there for the .ui-datepicker class and definately nothing that ever explains why are lines through the calendar.

Can anyone give me some advice or some pointers and how to clean this up (the icon and the calendar layout), or more generally, how to clean up gremlins when using custom themes?

Comment: show the `vm.dateOptions` values

Comment: var dateFormat = 'yyyy-MM-dd';
    vm.dateOptions = {
        formatYear: 'yy',
        startingDay: 1,
        showWeeks: false
    };

Comment: Just an observation that most of those "Bootstrap datepickers" are very hard to deal with on touch devices, fat fingers and all. Even on tablets and on small viewports you have to scroll down. This one is fluid and big: http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/ - easy enough to use instead. The size on the default sizes fairly well down to 240px the smallest device width, probably make a little bit smaller font size at a max-width and you're good to go.

Answer (score 2):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Bootstrap datepicket demo</title>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js'></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css">
    <script type='text/javascript' src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<style>
.datepicker-dropdown {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 4px;
  background-color: #2C6E8E;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.datepicker table {
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;

}

.datepicker table tr td,
.datepicker table tr th {
  text-align: center;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.datepicker table tr td.day:hover,
.datepicker table tr td.focused {
  background: #555555;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.datepicker table tr td.old,
.datepicker table tr td.new {
  color: #FF8000;
}

.datepicker table tr td.today {
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #FFA953;
  border-color: #FFB76F;
}
.datepicker table tr td.today:hover {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #884400;
  border-color: #f59e00;
}
.datepicker table tr td.active:active,
.datepicker table tr td.active.highlighted:active,
.datepicker table tr td.active.active,
.datepicker table tr td.active.highlighted.active,
.open > .dropdown-toggle.datepicker table tr td.active,
.open > .dropdown-toggle.datepicker table tr td.active.highlighted {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #419841;
  border-color: #285e8e;
}


.datepicker table tr td.active:active:hover,
.datepicker table tr td.active.highlighted:active:hover,
.datepicker table tr td.active.active:hover,
.datepicker table tr td.active.highlighted.active:hover,
.open > .dropdown-toggle.datepicker table tr td.active:hover,
.open > .dropdown-toggle.datepicker table tr td.active.highlighted:hover,
.datepicker table tr td.active:active:focus,
.datepicker table tr td.active.highlighted:active:focus,
.datepicker table tr td.active.active:focus,
.datepicker table tr td.active.highlighted.active:focus,
.open > .dropdown-toggle.datepicker table tr td.active:focus,
.open > .dropdown-toggle.datepicker table tr td.active.highlighted:focus,
.datepicker table tr td.active:active.focus,
.datepicker table tr td.active.highlighted:active.focus,
.datepicker table tr td.active.active.focus,
.datepicker table tr td.active.highlighted.active.focus,
.open > .dropdown-toggle.datepicker table tr td.active.focus,
.open > .dropdown-toggle.datepicker table tr td.active.highlighted.focus {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #285e8e;
  border-color: #193c5a;
}
.datepicker table tr td.active:active,
.datepicker table tr td.active.highlighted:active,
.datepicker table tr td.active.active,
.datepicker table tr td.active.highlighted.active,
.open > .dropdown-toggle.datepicker table tr td.active,
.open > .dropdown-toggle.datepicker table tr td.active.highlighted {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #3071a9;
  border-color: #285e8e;
}
.datepicker table tr td.active:active:hover,
.datepicker table tr td.active.highlighted:active:hover,
.datepicker table tr td.active.active:hover,
.datepicker table tr td.active.highlighted.active:hover,
.open > .dropdown-toggle.datepicker table tr td.active:hover,
.open > .dropdown-toggle.datepicker table tr td.active.highlighted:hover,
.datepicker table tr td.active:active:focus,
.datepicker table tr td.active.highlighted:active:focus,
.datepicker table tr td.active.active:focus,
.datepicker table tr td.active.highlighted.active:focus,
.open > .dropdown-toggle.datepicker table tr td.active:focus,
.open > .dropdown-toggle.datepicker table tr td.active.highlighted:focus,
.datepicker table tr td.active:active.focus,
.datepicker table tr td.active.highlighted:active.focus,
.datepicker table tr td.active.active.focus,
.datepicker table tr td.active.highlighted.active.focus,
.open > .dropdown-toggle.datepicker table tr td.active.focus,
.open > .dropdown-toggle.datepicker table tr td.active.highlighted.focus {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #285e8e;
  border-color: #193c5a;
}
.datepicker .datepicker-switch {
  width: 145px;
  
}
.datepicker .datepicker-switch:hover,
.datepicker .prev:hover,
.datepicker .next:hover,
.datepicker tfoot tr th:hover {
  background: #50A2C9;
}
</style>

<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function(){
$('.input-group.date').datepicker({
    orientation: "auto left",
    forceParse: false,
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true,
    toggleActive: true
});
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<h1>Custom datepicker</h1>
<div class="input-group date">
  <input type="text" class="form-control"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this will help you and also check this [Link](https://www.jquery-az.com/bootstrap-datepicker-set-up-guide-with-8-online-demos-and-code/) for reference.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue and it fixed by adding this class in `dateOptions`

```
vm.dateOptions = {
    class: 'datepicker'
};
```

**css**

```
.datepicker .btn-default {
  border-width: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

this will disable the `shadow` of button and get rid of borders

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Didn't make any difference.